# Android google maps not displaying all users location from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a google maps activity to display the location of all the users from Firebase Realtime database. What the problem is it only ever displays one user from the database. I have even tried hard coding two different lat longs and adding them to a marker then adding the marker to the map and only one marker appears again. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong. Can someone please help.

```
    public class ShowUsersOnMap extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    Location currentLocation;
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    private String userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    private ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_users_on_map);
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        fetchLastLocation();
        //listOfUsers();
    }

    public void fetchLastLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE);
            return;
        }
        Task<Location> task = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(location -> {
            if (location != null) {
                currentLocation = location;
                Log.i("LAT", String.valueOf(currentLocation.getLatitude()));
                Log.i("LAT", String.valueOf(currentLocation.getLongitude()));
                SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                assert supportMapFragment != null;
                supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(ShowUsersOnMap.this);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        //first lets print the current user logged in
//        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child(userID);
//        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
//                User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
//                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(user.getLatitude(), user.getLongitude());
//                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("My Position");
//                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
//                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 5));
//                googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
//            }
//
//            @Override
//            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
//                Toast.makeText(ShowUsersOnMap.this, "Error Occurred: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            }
//        });

        //now lets print all the other users in the database
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User");
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = userSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    assert user != null;
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(user.getLatitude(), user.getLongitude()))
                            .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                            .title(user.getUserName()));
//                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(user.getLatitude(), user.getLongitude());
//                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(user.getUserName());
//                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
//                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 5));
//                    googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(ShowUsersOnMap.this, "Error Occurred: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                fetchLastLocation();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: As you can see in the above method onMapReady I have commented out 2 other attempts but I cannot see what is wrong with them logically :(

Comment: one thing I have noticed is if I go into firebase and change the lat and long to a different location it then shows all the markers on the map

Comment: is it not possible to have the same lat longs and display them all?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the way forward for this question after a lot of investigating. One may note that if you hardcode two different lat and longs and add them to a marker then to a map it will display both the markers. The next step would be to read from the Realtime database and add markers for the users on the map. The problem was I am coding in my house so all my users have the same location. the reason the map is only showing one marker at my location is because theyre all overlapping each other. The solution for this is to either see if a marker exists at the same location and you can do this by a simple if statement. if the the statement is correct you can move the next marker the slightest bit. the other solution is to show a cluster of markers.